# Inline Checkboxes Display Properly in Chrome & Safari but not FireFox & IE

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website running on Rails that uses Bootstrap.  Inline checkboxes render fine in Chrome and Safari but not in Firefox or IE.

[Chrome or Safari (Correct)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LggU1.png)
The checkbox is to the left of the label.

[Firefox or IE (Not correct)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4V57e.png)
The checkbox is centered in the label which is not correct.

I have added the Bootstrap gem to my rails app.

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
```

**custom.css.scss**

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

**login.html.erb**

```
<%= f.label :remember_me, :class => "checkbox-inline" do %>
      <%= f.check_box :remember_me%>Remember me on this computer?
<% end %>
```

The code as it is rendered in the browser

```
<label class="checkbox-inline" for="session_remember_me">
      <input name="session[remember_me]" type="hidden" value="0">
      <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="session[remember_me]" id="session_remember_me">Remember me on this computer?
</label>
```

I've added the Bootstrap CDN in a test Rails app and the checkboxes rendered properly in all browsers.  I'm not opposed to removing the Bootstrap gem and switching to CDN but wanted to consult the SO crowd first.  Has anyone seen this before?  Is there any easier solution?

Thanks!

David

Comment: Please provide related CSS or a link to the online version if possible

Comment: Wanted to *bump* this one to see if anyone else had any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I got this working last night.

I added the following to my .css

```
/*Check box in the middle of the text fix*/

.checkbox {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    float: left;

}
.checkbox-inline {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 15px


}

.radio {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    float: left;

}
.radio-inline {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 15px;

}
```

This is an example of what I was doing in my View that was resulting in the checkbox being in the middle of the label text.

```
  <%= f.label :remember_me, :class => "checkbox-inline" do %>
      <%= f.check_box :remember_me%>Remember me on this computer?
  <%= end %>
```

I changed it to this:

```
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <%= f.check_box :remember_me, class: "checkbox" %>
    Remember me on this computer?
</label>
```

You may have to play with the `padding-left` to get it to look right.  So far this has fixed my issue on Firefox and IE 11, it still renders correctly in Safari and Chrome.

Good luck!